# How to obtain Image details of unpublished images

Tags: azure-powershell

I have been using the Azure PowerShell module and I use this cmdlet to obtain either published or unpublished image details:

```
Get-AzureVMImage | where-object { $_.Label -like "$ImageName" }
```

I need to move to the Az module. The replacement cmdlet seems to be Get-AzVMImage. And that does not seem to provide a way to list **unpublished** images.

So, how do you obtain a list of unpublished images and their details?
[image: Azure Portal Listing]

Answer (score 1):

According to my understanding, you want to get the custom image. If so you can use the command "[Get-AzImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azimage?view=azps-2.6.0)" to get it.  For example:

```
Connect-AzAccount -Subscription "your subscrition id" -Tenant "your tenant id"
 Get-AzImage -ImageName "" -ResourceGroupName ""
```

[image]

Comment: I need to list Classic VM Images. I've edited my original post to show the Portal listing that I need.

Comment: Hi. According to my research, the Az module is used to manage Azure Resource Management resource. It cannot be used to manage Azure classic resource. If you want to manage Azure classic resource, you need to Azure Service Management module : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/servicemanagement/overview?view=azuresmps-4.0.0

Comment: I've re-written my script to not use Classic Images. Better to move forward.

Comment: @RobG Ok. If you do not want to list classic image. you can use the command ```Get-AzImage``` to get the image you create or the command ```Get-AzVMImage``` to get the published image.

Comment: Jim Xu's comment is the nub of it. Not a solution to the issue of listing Classic Images with the Az module, because you cannot, it seems. But at least its clear how to proceed.